# Getting errors when intl is imported

Tags: dart, dart-intl

When i add `intl: ^0.17.0` to `pubspec.yaml`

i get the following errors:

```
../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/intl-0.17.0/lib/intl_browser.dart:12:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:html'
import 'dart:html';
       ^
../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/intl-0.17.0/lib/intl_browser.dart:24:48: Error: Undefined name 'window'.
  Intl.systemLocale = Intl.canonicalizedLocale(window.navigator.language);
                                               ^^^^^^
```

This only happens when the intl package is added.

How can i fix this?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that i had imported: `package:intl/intl_browser.dart`

instead of: `package:intl/intl.dart`